# Is payble keyword neccessary even if I am not taking any ether/matic?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20, erc721

```
 function sendGift(uint256 _mintAmount,address recipient) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount<= availableSupplyForSale);
    //require(_amount >= cost * _mintAmount);
    require(coinToken.allowance(msg.sender,address(this))>=cost * _mintAmount);
      coinToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),cost * _mintAmount);
    if(supply<currentSupply){
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(recipient, supply + i);
    }
    }
    else{
         uint256[] memory tokenIds = walletOfOwner(address(this));
         for(uint256 i=1;i<=_mintAmount;i++)
        transferFrom(address(this),recipient,tokenIds[i]);
    }
  }
```

Do I need to use payable here? Contract does not take any matic. It only takes custom token as payment .

```
(bool os, ) = payable(admin).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(os);
```

Also since I am not taking any matic, will this above line necessary for withdraw assets from contract as an owner? I have a sense that this above line only is useful to withdraw eth/polygon.

I am a new blockchain kid. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `payable` modifier of a function is required when your function accepts native tokens (ETH, BNB, MATIC, ... depending on the network).

So in this case, you can safely remove it from the function header.

```
// removed `payable`
function sendGift(uint256 _mintAmount,address recipient) public {
```

---

The low-level `.call()` also doesn't require using `payable` to send native tokens.

```
payable(admin).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
```

However, if you used the high-level `.transfer()`, then you'd need to cast the `admin` variable type `address` to its extension type `address payable` using the typecasting function.

```
// will not work as it's type `address`
admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

```
// need to cast type `address` to type `address payable`
payable(admin).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

---

In order to withdraw tokens from your contract address, you need to invoke the `transfer()` function (defined in the [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard) on the token contract. Do not confuse it with the native `transfer()` function of `address payable`, these are two separate things, just with the same name.

```
interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address, uint256) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {
    function withdrawToken() {
        IERC20(tokenContractAddress).transfer(recipient, amount);
    }
}
```